# Does anyone have any good examples of a Heuristic Evaluation report?

Tags: guidelines, heuristics

Looking for something that is well laid out & easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, since a Heuristic Evaluation report would show data collected from multiple sources and an aggregate of that data, the simplest format would be a bar chart with overlays.

Having said that, I think adding some design approaches common in infographics might go a long way towards improving legibility and adding impact.  While these examples aren't specifically tied to Heuristic Evaluation data, the approach would translate fairly cleanly.

http://awesome.good.is/transparency/web/0905/trans0509nomorefishinthesea.html

http://www.flickr.com/photos/bartclaeys/3351321706/sizes/o/
(I especially like the circular bar at the bottom.)

http://www.dominicforest.name/wp-content/photo_visualisation/graphical_text_similarity.jpg
(A bit more abstract.)

http://www.dominicforest.name/wp-content/photo_visualisation/flare.jpg
(Even more abstract.)

I think I would approach a report display by using vertical height to represent positive/negative heuristic value, horizontal value to be the categories evaluated, and colors to indicate either strength of compliancy or to organize sections of the report by sub-categories if there are a significant number of categories.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for nice samples, but.. The "circular bar" has a nice touch, but I  am scepttical about gratuitous 3D in presenting numbers, since this is one oo the cases where perspective waters down relative sizes, and is often used to manipulate the viewer.

Comment: The trouble with just distilling it down to some simple graphics - is that it can hide the vagueness of the underlying heuristics